# Sitecore Publishing Service 1.8.0 does not publish blob data for custom field using type Attachment

Tags: media-library, publishing-service

I've created a new file template called **Code** which contains many of the same fields as the **File** template but does not inherit it. While publishing using the Sitecore Publishing Service the blob data does not appear.

**Field:** Missing attachment

[image: Empty attachment field]

**Settings:** sc.global.xml

```xml
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <Publishing>
      <ConnectionStrings>
        <Master>user id=sa;password=pass123;data source=(local);database=demo.dev.localsitecore_Master;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;</Master>
        <Core>user id=sa;password=pass123;data source=(local);database=demo.dev.localsitecore_Core;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;</Core>
        <Web>user id=sa;password=pass123;data source=(local);database=demo.dev.localsitecore_Web;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;</Web>
      </ConnectionStrings>
      <LogLevel>Information</LogLevel>
    </Publishing>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Comment: Has the attachment file also been published?

Comment: Yes. The attachment field type is an existing field that is published.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the publishing service will publish Blobs if they are created/referenced by the following fields:

- /sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File/Media/Blob
  Guid = {DBBE7D99-1388-4357-BB34-AD71EDF18ED3}
- /sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/File/Media/Blob
  Guid = {40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}

In case of you defined your own field, you will need to configure the publishing service to use it. In order to do that, you can pass the new field Id to the RequiredPublishFieldsResolver options (check the sc.publishing.services.xml). Should be something like:

```xml
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <Publishing>
     <Services>
      <RequiredPublishFieldsResolver>
      <As>Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.IRequiredPublishFieldsResolver, Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Service.Abstractions</As>
      <Type>Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.RequiredPublishFieldsResolver, Sitecore.Framework.Publishing</Type>
      <Options>
        <AdditionalMediaFieldsIds>
          <Id>**The Guid of your Blob Field**</Id>
        </AdditionalMediaFieldsIds>
      </Options>
      </RequiredPublishFieldsResolver>
     </Services>
    </Publishing>
   </Sitecore>
  </Settings>
```

You can put this in a file (for example `codefield_patch.xml`) and place it in the `global` folder of the Publishing Service. This will mean it will be available for all environments (You can place it in 'developement' or 'production' folders to be environment specific - See the install guide for more info about these options)

Hope this helps

Comment: If I want to patch it where should the file be placed and recommend name?

Comment: I would put it config/global/sc.global.xml. this file has already some useful comments about how to patch the configuration of the publishing service

Comment: Ive made an edit to fix this .. waiting for peer review :)

Comment: Just a note if you need to add multiple field ids, the element names need to be unique.  e.g. 
...<Services>
   <RequiredPublishFieldsResolver>
     <Options>
        <AdditionalMediaFieldsIds>
          <Id1>B7ACF9B9-297F-45D2-943C-1B444B1C36FC</Id1>
          <Id2>FBC38F77-97B6-49D0-9F2A-C808F5B0CD42</Id2>
        </AdditionalMediaFieldsIds>
     </Options>
   </RequiredPublishFieldsResolver>
</Services>...